Squarespace analytics showing 20x more visits from Google Search Console. Why?
We have a relatively small corporate site hosted on Square Space. When looking at the analytis for the last 3 months, Squarespace reports roughly 600 visits from Google Searches in the Traffic Reports.
Looking at the same period in Google Search Console, our total clicks are 23.
I somewhat trust Google more, because they don't need to infer traffic sources; they know, but the discrepancy is so large I'm curious what could cause this.
One thought is that Squarespace's analytics is flawed and can't tell the difference between real search traffic or links from gmail, another is that Google Search Console uses a small sample size and do rough estimates, which fails because of our very low numbers.
Curious if there's an explanation for this that has a source or is somewhat verifiable.

My guess is that Squarespace is giving you every possible request and that Google is trying to weed out bots and spiders.

Bots and spiders typically don't set a Referral header though!
